# How to copy folder with contents in Doxygen generated HTML

Tags: doxygen

I have a folder with several SVG and xlsx files.
I want Doxygen to copy this folder into the generated HTML folder.
The HTML_EXTRA_FILES tag is set to the folder but does not copy the folder and contents.
How do I properly configure the Doxyfile so that the folder and its contents are copied in the generated HTML folder?

Comment: The intention of the `HTML_EXTRA_FILES` is to copy some files explicitly to the html directory. You want to copy entire directories (next would be with subdirectories preserving structure and hidden files), this is currently not possible so you have list all the files separately. I didn't test properly but an initial test showed that something like `HTML_EXTRA_FILES=$(MY_EXTRA_FILES)` might work, where you set (outside doxygen) the environment variable to the set of files e.g. on *nix like ``export MY_EXTRA_FILES=`ls -1` ``

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have resorted to using a post script that copies all the files in the HTML folder.